# C - Populating an array with a for loop

Tags: c, arrays, loops

My goal is this to write a for loop to populate array userGuesses with NUM_GUESSES.

I believe my only issue is with the first for loop. Can someone point me in the right direction? I would assume if it were C++ I would use something like cin in this case, but I'm not so sure with C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   const int NUM_GUESSES = 3;
   int userGuesses[NUM_GUESSES];
   int i = 0;

   for (i = 0; i < NUM_GUESSES; i++) {
      scanf("%d", i);
   }

   for (i = 0; i < NUM_GUESSES; ++i) {
      printf("%d ", userGuesses[i]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d", i);` ?? and even with `scanf("%d", &i);` you're not storing the result, you just changing the loop index variable.

Comment: do `scanf("%d", userGuesses+i);` pointer arithmetic will do the rest

Comment: Thanks for the help @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: The man-page for `scanf` and the other functions are quite clear. What about them is specifically not clear? If you don't know C, a good textbook would be a good investment (there are free ones, too).

Comment: @MichaelJohnson - do not edit the initial question to have the solution. It makes it confusing. To indicate that question is solved mark the answer that solved it for you

Comment: @GiladGreen I have changed it back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you read a number, where do you store it? You want the first number to be stored in the first cell of the array and so on..The i-th number to be stored in the i-th cell of the array.

Furthermore, you do not want your `i` counter to take the input value!

Moreover [scanf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) needs a pointer to the variable.

So, change this:

```
scanf("%d", i);
```

to this:

```
scanf("%d", &userGuesses[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the above scanf function call use followinf scanf statement - "scanf("%d", &userGuesses[i])"
I hope your issue will be solved

Comment: How does your answer differ from mine's? :/

Comment: @gsamaras I haven't seen your answer before posting mine. As i had some questions opened simultaneously.

Comment: Also, yes the answers are same.